# Server disconnecting client when receiving 1 packet string, but not another

Tags: python, server, client

I've run in to a strange problem in a multiplayer online game I'm developing.

When the user clicks "Accept Quest" on the client, it performs the following action:

```
packet = "A:io-QS#"
tcpClient.send(packet.encode('utf-8'))
```

On the server, there is a thread created for each client that handles sending/receiving data:

```
while (client[self.id].authenticated == True):
    try:
        data = (self.connection.recv(1024)).decode('utf-8')
        client[self.id].lastPacketTime = time.time()
        client[self.id].processData(data)
    except:
        print("Client disconnected due to data receive error")
        client[self.id].saveDataToDatabase()
        client[self.id].authenticated = False
        client[self.id].loggedIn = False
```

If the server receives the packet "A:io-QS#", it throws an exception and disconnects the client. I modified the client code mentioned aboe to send the packet "M:w#" (directional movement packet) and it doesn't throw an exception,
Only when the packet is "A:io-QS#".
The packet size isn't a concern (a much larger packet containing login credentials passes through this server loop just fine).
I tried commenting out the "client[self.id].processData(data)" line and the exception still occurs (but only with the packet 'A:io-QS#').
The server throws an exception after receiving the data but before acting upon it, so it's not a logic error.

I'm at a bit of a loss, does anybody see anything I'm missing or have any recommendations on how I could test this issue further?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using sys.exc_info() in the except block in the server to find more about the exception.

Comment: Thank you!
That led me to discovering that the error was in fact a typo that was in a 'update quest status' function that was called in the 'processData()' function.
Everything is working perfectly again, thank you very much!
I've also kept 'sys.exc_info()' in my try/except blocks in case this happens again.